# How connect to database with a web service in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-data-services

I,m developing a website with MVC and i wanna  connect to database with web service look like WCF and i do n't know anything about that.
This is my question how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start here,

1. User Tier
2. MVC app Tier
3. WCF Service Tier
4. SQL Server Tier
   ...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d13d20/creating-aspnet-mvc-app-with-wcf-service-docx/